# How can the purchase cost of a treasury bill be more than its face value?

Tags: united-states, interest, treasury

I'm considering (non-competitively) purchasing a 52-week Treasury bill through Treasury Direct.  As I understand, the purchase price is reduced by the discount rate and therefore is always less than the face value of the bill. So that if I purchase a bill for $1000 at 5% discount, I would expect to pay $950.

However, TreasuryDirect gives the following information when purchasing a bill:

> I understand that the total cost for my security purchase will be
> determined at auction through competitive bidding, and that the final
> cost of the security will not be known until after the auction results
> are announced. **I agree to pay the full purchase price, which could be
> less than, more than or equal to the principal amount I indicated
> above and that full payment must be made on the security's Issue Date**.

Could someone please explain to me how the full purchase price could be equal or more than the principal amount say if I purchased $1000 and the discount is 5%?

**Edit:  As per comments below, here's a plot of the 1-year treasury rate that shows near zero return during height of covid.  It briefly became negative at one point in March, 2020.**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The discount is determined at the auction, no-one guarantees you the 5%. You may end up paying more than the face value if at the auction the discount becomes negative (i.e.: becomes a premium), which is also referred to as "negative interest". While highly unlikely, the warning tells you that if it does happen - you'll be on the hook for the money.

Comment: @josh The place to look is not the US, but the Eurozone, which had negative interest rates from 2014-2022. Japan also had some negative yield bonds in the same timeframe.

Comment: @user71659:  I also found the yield on 1 and 3 month treasury bills briefly dipped below zero in March, 2020 due to near zero Fed rate and covid.